# php : manually create a array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

### NEW Update

How will you write a array which output will be like this: 
`Array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#29 (15) {  ["cals"]=> string(11) "1545.616024" } }`

### OLD UPDATE

I am trying to manually insert value in a array if My db is resulting 0 results.

I am trying to create a manually a array which stores value as this  model function  stores

```
public function fetch_LifeStyeActivity_byid($activityDate, $uid) {
         ----
         ----
        $query = $this->db->order_by('calorie_activity.ordering', 'ASC')->get_where('calorie_activity', array('creater_id' => $uid,'activity_date' => $activityDate, 'parent_id =' => '625'));
        $data = array();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am creating it like this from my controller like this

```
  $data["lifeStyle_activity_query"] = array( 
    "cals"  => "6" 
);
 $this->load->view('weight_lose/activities', $data);
```

& in view page while retrieving i am getting exception

```
 foreach ($lifeStyle_activity_query as $row) {
  echo $row->cals;
}
```

Exception getting as:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Note:  I only need help  on modifying controller logic(please do not tell to change the view page  code)

Comment: @Debflav can you help me to modify in my controller code, because i can not change the code of view page..

Comment: what is $lifeStyle_activity_query? it seems from your code like Style_activity_query is name of one subarray from $data.Should not it be foreach ($data["lifeStyle_activity_query"] ...

Comment: @BojanKovacevic lifeStyle_activity_query is the data return by model method fetch_LifeStyeActivity_byid  (like: $this->activitymodel->fetch_LifeStyeActivity_byid($activityDate, $userid);))

Comment: did you try to print_r($lifeStyle_activity_query);

Comment: @BojanKovacevic How will you write a array which gives output as: 
`Array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#29 (15) {  ["cals"]=> string(11) "1545.616024" } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error simply comes from the fact that you've an array and try to use it as an object. You could just cast your array into an object so it can be used as such in your view.

```
$data["lifeStyle_activity_query"] = array( 
    "cals"  => "6" 
);

$data["lifeStyle_activity_query"] = (object) $data["lifeStyle_activity_query"];
echo $data["lifeStyle_activity_query"]->cals; // -> 6
```

Edit for your update :

```
$val['cals'] = '1545.616024';
$arr[0] = (object) $val;
```

Comment: i have updated my question on the first line, just try to  answer it & that will be solution for my doubt.. Thanks

Comment: if i write:  $this->load->view('weight_lose/activities', $data);  & return data into my view page , do you think your first edit will work?

Comment: @Sundara My original post answers your exception problem. You were using `$row->cals` on an array, my code turns that array into an object, so you will be able to access `->cals`. But now, I don't know anything about your view, I just assumed that `$data["lifeStyle_activity_query"]` becomes equal to `$lifeStyle_activity_query`.

Comment: yes but i have to use output as :  
                           `foreach ($lifeStyle_activity_query as $row) {
  echo $row->cals;
}`    Does your 1st edit will work?

Comment: @Sundara Hey, why don't you just try it ? YES it SHOULD works. I don't have your whole code, so I can't say it will be 100%. Give it a try already.

Comment: @yeah i  tried your code, for showing output as `echo $data["lifeStyle_activity_query"]->cals;`  it is showing output but i can not use your technique to show , i want to see the same output in foreach loop,  because this code is dependent on other code, if i change it to show as you r saying , then it will effect other code functionality